# Biased coins strategy

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, expected-value

**Question**: Suppose that I have $n$ different biased coins, where each coin's probability $p$ of flipping heads is drawn independently and uniformly from $(0,1)$. I need to devise a scheme to generate the flip of fair coin as close to random as possible (i.e. as close to a $50-50$ flip as possible). How could I do this? How many coin tosses would I need, so I can be sure about getting a $50-50$ flip?

Could I use this strategy if I didn't know that the probabilities were distributed at random?

**Thoughts**: Maybe if we prove that if we have k coins, we can get k flips of a 50-50 coin by just flipping them in sequence? (because of the continuous distribution of $p$) Now we flip one coin and that provides us more information about it, and we do this with every coin. I'm not sure how to implement this strategy, and if we can ever be *sure* about a $50-50$ flip.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is what you want, but suppose you have just one coin with a probability $p\in(0,1)$ of flipping  $\mathrm{H}$. Then, flip the coin twice. If it goes $\mathrm{HH}$ or $\mathrm{TT}$, then discard the trial and repeat. If it goes $\mathrm{HT}$, then call this event "Heads", and if it goes $\mathrm{TH}$, then call this event "Tails". These two events are equiprobable.

Comment: What's the point of $n$ coins, then?